# Render Dynamic tables in docx template?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, xml, quote-template

Hey I've been trying to generate docx templates using jsZip but i'm struck with generating tables how to get the table columns and run soql query to generate table and the document.xml
format for above code is

Sample table xml for DOCX file

```
    <w:tbl xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
                <w:tblPr>
                    <w:tblStyle w:val="Table2"/>
                    <w:tblW w:w="10800.0" w:type="dxa"/>
                    <w:jc w:val="center"/>
                    <w:tblBorders>
                        <w:top w:color="000000" w:space="0" w:sz="4" w:val="single"/>
                        <w:left w:color="000000" w:space="0" w:sz="4" w:val="single"/>
                        <w:bottom w:color="000000" w:space="0" w:sz="4" w:val="single"/>
                        <w:right w:color="000000" w:space="0" w:sz="4" w:val="single"/>
                        <w:insideH w:color="000000" w:space="0" w:sz="4" w:val="single"/>
                        <w:insideV w:color="000000" w:space="0" w:sz="4" w:val="single"/>
                    </w:tblBorders>
                    <w:tblLayout w:type="fixed"/>
                    <w:tblLook w:val="0600"/>
                </w:tblPr>
                <w:tblGrid>
                    <w:gridCol w:w="1410"/>
                    <w:gridCol w:w="3990"/>
                    <w:gridCol w:w="2715"/>
                    <w:gridCol w:w="2685"/>
                    <w:tblGridChange w:id="0">
                        <w:tblGrid>
                            <w:gridCol w:w="1410"/>
                            <w:gridCol w:w="3990"/>
                            <w:gridCol w:w="2715"/>
                            <w:gridCol w:w="2685"/>
                        </w:tblGrid>
                    </w:tblGridChange>
                </w:tblGrid>
                <w:tr>
                    <w:trPr>
                        <w:cantSplit w:val="0"/>
                        <w:trHeight w:val="145.95703125" w:hRule="atLeast"/>
                        <w:tblHeader w:val="0"/>
                    </w:trPr>
                    <w:tc>
                        <w:tcPr>
                            <w:tcBorders>
                                <w:top w:color="ffffff" w:space="0" w:sz="4" w:val="single"/>
                                <w:left w:color="ffffff" w:space="0" w:sz="4" w:val="single"/>
                                <w:bottom w:color="000000" w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                <w:right w:color="ffffff" w:space="0" w:sz="4" w:val="single"/>
                            </w:tcBorders>
                            <w:shd w:fill="f68744" w:val="clear"/>
                            <w:tcMar>
                                <w:top w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa"/>
                                <w:left w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa"/>
                                <w:bottom w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa"/>
                                <w:right w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa"/>
                            </w:tcMar>
                            <w:vAlign w:val="center"/>
                        </w:tcPr>
                        <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidP="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" w14:paraId="0000000E">    
                            <w:pPr>
                                <w:keepNext w:val="0"/>
                                <w:keepLines w:val="0"/>
                                <w:pageBreakBefore w:val="0"/>
                                <w:widowControl w:val="0"/>
                                <w:pBdr>
                                    <w:top w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                    <w:left w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                    <w:bottom w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                    <w:right w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                    <w:between w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                </w:pBdr>
                                <w:shd w:fill="auto" w:val="clear"/>
                                <w:spacing w:after="0" w:before="0" w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto"/>
                                <w:ind w:left="0" w:right="0" w:firstLine="0"/>
                                <w:jc w:val="center"/>
                                <w:rPr>
                                    <w:b w:val="1"/>
                                    <w:color w:val="ffffff"/>
                                </w:rPr>
                            </w:pPr>
                            <w:r w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000">
                                <w:rPr>
                                    <w:b w:val="1"/>
                                    <w:color w:val="ffffff"/>
                                    <w:rtl w:val="0"/>
                                </w:rPr>
                                <w:t xml:space="preserve">Qty</w:t>
                            </w:r>
                        </w:p>
                    </w:tc>
                    <w:tc>
                        <w:tcPr>
                            <w:tcBorders>
                                <w:top w:color="ffffff" w:space="0" w:sz="4" w:val="single"/>
                                <w:left w:color="ffffff" w:space="0" w:sz="4" w:val="single"/>
                                <w:bottom w:color="000000" w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                <w:right w:color="ffffff" w:space="0" w:sz="4" w:val="single"/>
                            </w:tcBorders>
                            <w:shd w:fill="f68744" w:val="clear"/>
                            <w:tcMar>
                                <w:top w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa"/>
                                <w:left w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa"/>
                                <w:bottom w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa"/>
                                <w:right w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa"/>
                            </w:tcMar>
                            <w:vAlign w:val="center"/>
                        </w:tcPr>
                        <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidP="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000" w14:paraId="0000000F">
                            <w:pPr>
                                <w:keepNext w:val="0"/>
                                <w:keepLines w:val="0"/>
                                <w:pageBreakBefore w:val="0"/>
                                <w:widowControl w:val="0"/>
                                <w:pBdr>
                                    <w:top w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                    <w:left w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                    <w:bottom w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                    <w:right w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                    <w:between w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                </w:pBdr>
                                <w:shd w:fill="auto" w:val="clear"/>
                                <w:spacing w:after="0" w:before="0" w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto"/>
                                <w:ind w:left="0" w:right="0" w:firstLine="0"/>
                                <w:jc w:val="center"/>
                                <w:rPr>
                                    <w:b w:val="1"/>
                                    <w:color w:val="ffffff"/>
                                </w:rPr>
                            </w:pPr>
                            <w:r w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000">
                                <w:rPr>
                                    <w:b w:val="1"/>
                                    <w:color w:val="ffffff"/>
                                    <w:rtl w:val="0"/>
                                </w:rPr>
                                <w:t xml:space="preserve">Description</w:t>
                            </w:r>
                        </w:p>
                    </w:tc>
                    <w:tc>
                        <w:tcPr>
                            <w:tcBorders>
                                <w:top w:color="ffffff" w:space="0" w:sz="4" w:val="single"/>
                                <w:left w:color="ffffff" w:space="0" w:sz="4" w:val="single"/>
                                <w:bottom w:color="000000" w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                <w:right w:color="ffffff" w:space="0" w:sz="4" w:val="single"/>
                            </w:tcBorders>
                            <w:shd w:fill="f68744" w:val="clear"/>
                            <w:tcMar>
                                <w:top w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa"/>
                                <w:left w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa"/>
                                <w:bottom w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa"/>
                                <w:right w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa"/>
                            </w:tcMar>
                            <w:vAlign w:val="center"/>
                        </w:tcPr>
                        <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidP="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000" w14:paraId="00000010">
                            <w:pPr>
                                <w:keepNext w:val="0"/>
                                <w:keepLines w:val="0"/>
                                <w:pageBreakBefore w:val="0"/>
                                <w:widowControl w:val="0"/>
                                <w:pBdr>
                                    <w:top w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                    <w:left w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                    <w:bottom w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                    <w:right w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                    <w:between w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                </w:pBdr>
                                <w:shd w:fill="auto" w:val="clear"/>
                                <w:spacing w:after="0" w:before="0" w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto"/>
                                <w:ind w:left="0" w:right="0" w:firstLine="0"/>
                                <w:jc w:val="center"/>
                                <w:rPr>
                                    <w:b w:val="1"/>
                                    <w:color w:val="ffffff"/>
                                </w:rPr>
                            </w:pPr>
                            <w:r w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000">
                                <w:rPr>
                                    <w:b w:val="1"/>
                                    <w:color w:val="ffffff"/>
                                    <w:rtl w:val="0"/>
                                </w:rPr>
                                <w:t xml:space="preserve">Unit Price</w:t>
                            </w:r>
                        </w:p>
                    </w:tc>
                    <w:tc>
                        <w:tcPr>
                            <w:tcBorders>
                                <w:top w:color="ffffff" w:space="0" w:sz="4" w:val="single"/>
                                <w:left w:color="ffffff" w:space="0" w:sz="4" w:val="single"/>
                                <w:bottom w:color="000000" w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                <w:right w:color="ffffff" w:space="0" w:sz="4" w:val="single"/>
                            </w:tcBorders>
                            <w:shd w:fill="f68744" w:val="clear"/>
                            <w:tcMar>
                                <w:top w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa"/>
                                <w:left w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa"/>
                                <w:bottom w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa"/>
                                <w:right w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa"/>
                            </w:tcMar>
                            <w:vAlign w:val="center"/>
                        </w:tcPr>
                        <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidP="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000" w14:paraId="00000011">
                            <w:pPr>
                                <w:keepNext w:val="0"/>
                                <w:keepLines w:val="0"/>
                                <w:pageBreakBefore w:val="0"/>
                                <w:widowControl w:val="0"/>
                                <w:pBdr>
                                    <w:top w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                    <w:left w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                    <w:bottom w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                    <w:right w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                    <w:between w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                </w:pBdr>
                                <w:shd w:fill="auto" w:val="clear"/>
                                <w:spacing w:after="0" w:before="0" w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto"/>
                                <w:ind w:left="0" w:right="0" w:firstLine="0"/>
                                <w:jc w:val="center"/>
                                <w:rPr>
                                    <w:b w:val="1"/>
                                </w:rPr>
                            </w:pPr>
                            <w:r w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000">
                                <w:rPr>
                                    <w:b w:val="1"/>
                                    <w:color w:val="ffffff"/>
                                    <w:rtl w:val="0"/>
                                </w:rPr>
                                <w:t xml:space="preserve">Amount</w:t>
                            </w:r>
                            <w:r w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000">
                                <w:rPr>
                                    <w:rtl w:val="0"/>
                                </w:rPr>
                                <w:t xml:space="preserve">{{forEach:OpportunityLineItems}}</w:t>
                            </w:r>
                            <w:r w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000">
                                <w:rPr>
                                    <w:rtl w:val="0"/>
                                </w:rPr>
                            </w:r>
                        </w:p>
                    </w:tc>
                </w:tr>
                <w:tr>
                    <w:trPr>
                        <w:cantSplit w:val="0"/>
                        <w:tblHeader w:val="0"/>
                    </w:trPr>
                    <w:tc>
                        <w:tcPr>
                            <w:tcBorders>
                                <w:top w:color="000000" w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                <w:left w:color="000000" w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                <w:bottom w:color="000000" w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                <w:right w:color="000000" w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                            </w:tcBorders>
                            <w:shd w:fill="auto" w:val="clear"/>
                            <w:tcMar>
                                <w:top w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa"/>
                                <w:left w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa"/>
                                <w:bottom w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa"/>
                                <w:right w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa"/>
                            </w:tcMar>
                            <w:vAlign w:val="top"/>
                        </w:tcPr>
                        <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidP="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000" w14:paraId="00000012">
                            <w:pPr>
                                <w:jc w:val="center"/>
                                <w:rPr/>
                            </w:pPr>
                            <w:r w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000">
                                <w:rPr>
                                    <w:rtl w:val="0"/>
                                </w:rPr>
                                <w:t xml:space="preserve">{{Quantity}}</w:t>
                            </w:r>
                        </w:p>
                    </w:tc>
                    <w:tc>
                        <w:tcPr>
                            <w:tcBorders>
                                <w:top w:color="000000" w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                <w:left w:color="000000" w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                <w:bottom w:color="000000" w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                <w:right w:color="000000" w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                            </w:tcBorders>
                            <w:shd w:fill="auto" w:val="clear"/>
                            <w:tcMar>
                                <w:top w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa"/>
                                <w:left w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa"/>
                                <w:bottom w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa"/>
                                <w:right w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa"/>
                            </w:tcMar>
                            <w:vAlign w:val="top"/>
                        </w:tcPr>
                        <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidP="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000" w14:paraId="00000013">
                            <w:pPr>
                                <w:keepNext w:val="0"/>
                                <w:keepLines w:val="0"/>
                                <w:pageBreakBefore w:val="0"/>
                                <w:widowControl w:val="0"/>
                                <w:pBdr>
                                    <w:top w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                    <w:left w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                    <w:bottom w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                    <w:right w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                    <w:between w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                </w:pBdr>
                                <w:shd w:fill="auto" w:val="clear"/>
                                <w:spacing w:after="0" w:before="0" w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto"/>
                                <w:ind w:left="0" w:right="0" w:firstLine="0"/>
                                <w:rPr/>
                            </w:pPr>
                            <w:r w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000">
                                <w:rPr>
                                    <w:rtl w:val="0"/>
                                </w:rPr>
                                <w:t xml:space="preserve">{{Product2.Name}}</w:t>
                            </w:r>
                        </w:p>
                    </w:tc>
                    <w:tc>
                        <w:tcPr>
                            <w:tcBorders>
                                <w:top w:color="000000" w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                <w:left w:color="000000" w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                <w:bottom w:color="000000" w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                <w:right w:color="000000" w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                            </w:tcBorders>
                            <w:shd w:fill="auto" w:val="clear"/>
                            <w:tcMar>
                                <w:top w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa"/>
                                <w:left w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa"/>
                                <w:bottom w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa"/>
                                <w:right w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa"/>
                            </w:tcMar>
                            <w:vAlign w:val="top"/>
                        </w:tcPr>
                        <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidP="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000" w14:paraId="00000014">
                            <w:pPr>
                                <w:keepNext w:val="0"/>
                                <w:keepLines w:val="0"/>
                                <w:pageBreakBefore w:val="0"/>
                                <w:widowControl w:val="0"/>
                                <w:pBdr>
                                    <w:top w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                    <w:left w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                    <w:bottom w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                    <w:right w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                    <w:between w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                </w:pBdr>
                                <w:shd w:fill="auto" w:val="clear"/>
                                <w:spacing w:after="0" w:before="0" w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto"/>
                                <w:ind w:left="0" w:right="0" w:firstLine="0"/>
                                <w:jc w:val="right"/>
                                <w:rPr/>
                            </w:pPr>
                            <w:r w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000">
                                <w:rPr>
                                    <w:rtl w:val="0"/>
                                </w:rPr>
                                <w:t xml:space="preserve">{{ListPrice}}</w:t>
                            </w:r>
                        </w:p>
                    </w:tc>
                    <w:tc>
                        <w:tcPr>
                            <w:tcBorders>
                                <w:top w:color="000000" w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                <w:left w:color="000000" w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                <w:bottom w:color="000000" w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                <w:right w:color="000000" w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                            </w:tcBorders>
                            <w:shd w:fill="auto" w:val="clear"/>
                            <w:tcMar>
                                <w:top w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa"/>
                                <w:left w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa"/>
                                <w:bottom w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa"/>
                                <w:right w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa"/>
                            </w:tcMar>
                            <w:vAlign w:val="top"/>
                        </w:tcPr>
                        <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidP="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000" w14:paraId="00000015">
                            <w:pPr>
                                <w:keepNext w:val="0"/>
                                <w:keepLines w:val="0"/>
                                <w:pageBreakBefore w:val="0"/>
                                <w:widowControl w:val="0"/>
                                <w:pBdr>
                                    <w:top w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                    <w:left w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                    <w:bottom w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                    <w:right w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                    <w:between w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil"/>
                                </w:pBdr>
                                <w:shd w:fill="auto" w:val="clear"/>
                                <w:spacing w:after="0" w:before="0" w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto"/>
                                <w:ind w:left="0" w:right="0" w:firstLine="0"/>
                                <w:jc w:val="right"/>
                                <w:rPr/>
                            </w:pPr>
                            <w:r w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000">
                                <w:rPr>
                                    <w:rtl w:val="0"/>
                                </w:rPr>
                                <w:t xml:space="preserve">{{TotalPrice}}{{/forEach:OpportunityLineItems}}</w:t>    
                            </w:r>
                        </w:p>
                    </w:tc>
                </w:tr>
            </w:tbl>
```

The javascript code to parse the xml is

```javascript
    const fs = require('fs');
    const { DOMParser } = require('xmldom');
    
    (function() {
        try {
            const data = fs.readFileSync('./document.xml', 'utf8');
            let parser = new DOMParser();
            let parsedXML = parser.parseFromString(data, 'text/xml');
            // Read all the tables
            const tableElements = parsedXML.getElementsByTagName('w:tbl');
            console.log(tableElements.length);
            for (let i = 0; i < tableElements.length; i++) {
                const tableContent = tableElements[i].textContent;
                if (tableContent.includes('forEach')) {
                    console.log(tableElements[i].toString());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    })();
```

I'm struct here

Comment: Is the plan to let a LWC generate this XML? Is this for Omnistudio or CPQ? What is the precise Salesforce context?

Comment: it is for salescloud I'm reading the .docx file using jszip and based on the placeholders I'm generating document form record data

Comment: In a LWC? If so, please present your LWC in your question. The Javascript you currently present is to be executed outside of Salesforce, which makes your question more suitable for Stackoverflow.